# How can I send a UDP message to all link local nodes using apple's Network framework?

Tags: swift, udp, ipv6, network.framework, network-framework

When I try to setup a connection, it changes from waiting(POSIXErrorCode: Network is down) to [preparing state](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/nwconnection/state/preparing). But it never goes into the [ready state](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/nwconnection/state/ready) and I can't figure out how to send a datagram.

```
import Network
import Dispatch

let connection = NWConnection(host: .ipv6(.linkLocalNodes), port: 9898, using: .udp)

connection.stateUpdateHandler = { state in print(state) }
connection.start(queue: DispatchQueue(label: "UDP"))
```

How can I send a UDP message to all link local nodes?

Comment: UDP is specifically connectionless.

Comment: @RonMaupin : OK but how do I send messages then? When I immediately send using: `connection.send(content: "Hello world, this is me".data(using: .utf8), completion: .idempotent)` The datagram is never sent.

Comment: @RonMaupin Never sent or never deliver?

Comment: Never sent. But anyway how do you suggest to send a datagram without an NWConnection?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to specify an interface for the link local multicast address. Sending to all interfaces does not work. So for example in my case I have to send to `.ipv6(IPv6Address("ff02::1%en4")!)` to send to all the local nodes on `en4`.